# AS3 - Get edge coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to move movieclip Ball along the borders of movieclip Ground. You would move the Ball with the arrow keys which would increase and decrease its x value, but the y value will always be equal to the top edge of the Ground movieclip.

To do this I need to find the y value of the points on the edges of movieclip Ground. How is this possible?
[image: Ground MovieClip]

This is what the Ground MovieClip would look like. It is an irregular shape. What I want is for any x point a y point at the top edge of this shape.

Comment: Please provide a screen-grab so we can see the shape of 'ground'  (hint, the question editor's image button provides uploading.)

Comment: @Mikushi @Slomojo Added a picture to give you a better idea if what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is all you want to do to, it should be easy to loop through columns of your bitmap data and for each one store a **y** value you can reference later to get a **y** for an **x**.
Here's a basic example:

```
//get values
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new Terrain(480,320);//Terrain is a reference to your image as BitmapData
var yValues:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(bitmapData.width,true);

for(var i:int = 0 ; i < bitmapData.width ; i++){
    for(var j:int = 0 ; j < bitmapData.height; j++){
        //this conditions might change based on the content of your image, black if fine for now
        if(bitmapData.getPixel(i,j) == 0) {
            yValues[i] = j;
            j = bitmapData.height;
        }else yValues[i] = bitmapData.height;
    }
}
//test values
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
var ball:Sprite = new Sprite();ball.graphics.lineStyle(5,0x009900);ball.graphics.drawCircle(-5,-5,5);
addChild(bitmap);
addChild(ball);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function update(event:Event):void {
    ball.x = mouseX;
    if(mouseX > 0 && mouseX <= bitmap.width) ball.y = yValues[mouseX];
}
```

[image: terrain]

If instead of 'caching values' you want to it for a scrolling terrain at run time, you could loop through a column of pixels(bitmapdata with width of 1 and height equal to your terrain bitmap) and get the value on the fly.

Your **hitTestPoint()** suggestion is also good. Bare in mind that the BitmapData class also has a hitTest method. Check out [Mike Chamber's posts](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/) on this.

Also, you might want to have a look at [Corey's Collision Detection Kit](http://www.coreyoneil.com/portfolio/index.php?project=5)

HTH

Answer (score 4):

george's technique is fine ( & probably the fastest ) for a static terrain.

if the terrain clip moves, it might become extremely expensive to compute : 2 nested loops to get the lookup table = ouch.

in this case, we can use the getcolorBoundsRect() ( != getBounds() :) ) property of the BitmapData.

with a bitmapdata called scene, it would give something like:

```
scene.fillRect( scene.rect, 0 );//clear bitmapdata
scene.draw( mc );//draw the clip

var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle( mouseX, 0, 1, scene.height );//create a 1px wide  rect at the desired X position
var slice:BitmapData = new BitmapData( 1, scene.height, true, 0 );// create a slice bitmapdata
slice.copyPixels( scene, rect, new Point );//draw the slice rect into the slice bitmapdata
return new Point( rect.x, slice.getColorBoundsRect( 0xff000000, 0, false ).topLeft.y );//retrieve the top left corner of the getColorBoundsRect
```

the top left corner of the slice's getColorBoundsRect() is the upper most non transparent pixel.
this is a pretty cheap test in terms of computation so it can be useed in a loop.

it's recommended not to create a 'slice' bitmapData each time though.

I've done a quick animated example :

- http://www.nicoptere.net/AS3/junkyard/bitmap_rect_test.swf
- the source is here: http://www.nicoptere.net/AS3/junkyard/BitmapRectTest.as
- I've just discovered the bullet points ^^

if you uncomment the //extract outline block, you'll get a cheap way to retrieve the pixels of the slope

Answer (score 2):

you can use [getbounds()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29) to get a rectangle

you can get that rectangle's top and left objects

Comment: We don't know that ground is a rectangle, and if we did Y would never change.

Comment: that's the way I interpret  "top edge of the Ground movieclip"

Comment: The Ground MovieClip is an irregular shape. I uploaded a picture to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Used a for loop to hitTestPoint(x_val,y_val,true) every point from ground.y until ground.y + ground.height. When a hit was found, that is my point.

Answer (score 1):

in that case, you could also use the [collision detection kit](http://www.coreyoneil.com/portfolio/index.php?project=5)